# Transmission : Change Finished Downloads Colour

Tags: 22.04, transmission

I have Ubuntu 22.04. Transmission works fine for me with torrents. But the same colour for active and finished downloads is a bit confusing.

From Google search, I see a few requests on the same on official channels, unattended.

Wondering whether it is possible to do it ourselves somehow. As in changing the downloaded torrent progress bar colour to green.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Which interface are you using, it *might* be very simple to fix (for you) if you're using the web interface; just by writing a line of CSS.

Comment: I am using what came with Ubuntu 22.04. I guess we can call it GTK.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the project [release notes](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/releases/) it seems that the beta `4.0.0-beta.2` already has that [feature](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/pull/3976) implemented. Not tried it myself but you could manually [download](https://transmissionbt.com/download) & install the beta and try it.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer. But not sure whether it is safe to use a software with possible bugs, especially while dealing with torrents.

Comment: All software has possible bugs - Transmission 3 has [huge memory leak issues](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/3077), that affects many users. I don't see the problem in using Transmission Beta.

Comment: @user227495 works the other way too: maybe there is a bug fixed in that version that has not trickled down to Ubuntu yet :) Very simple: install both (install the one from the link in /opt/) and you can switch to the one that works for you. I have been using the 4.0 beta for a bit now and love it :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I understand your viewpoint. If I may, the code is already there in 4.0, I do not understand enough c++ to port it to 3.0.